# How to transfer data from xlsx file in Google Drive to Google Sheet in same drive?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, looker-studio

Is there a way to write a script/automate copying over data from an xlsx file to a google sheet file in the same google drive?

I have the xlsx file to auto-sync in my google drive. I want to then connect this data to data studio report for visualization, but that is not compatible with an xlsx file. I need to transfer this data to a google sheet in order to connect, so I was wondering how I could automate the process of moving data from this xlsx file to a gsheet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project hosted on GitHub that has what you are looking for:

https://gist.github.com/azadisaryev/ab57e95096203edc2741

It creates the new GS file on GDrive from the existing xlsx file on your GDrive.

In your scenario you may want to read data from the newly created GS and put them into a "static" GS (connected to Data Studio). Then you may want to delete (send to trash) newly created GS file.

Answer (score 0):

This code convert XLSX to G Spread Sheet in specific folder. Update if file name (GSS) already exist.

Sure this helps XLSX2GSS.

```js
function XLSX2GSS() {
  var sourceFolderId = ""; // Folder ID including source files.
  var destinationFolderId = ""; // Folder ID that the converted files are put.

  var getFileIds = function (folder, fileList, q) {
    var files = folder.searchFiles(q);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var f = files.next();
      fileList.push({id: f.getId(), fileName: f.getName().split(".")[0].trim()});
    }
    var folders = folder.getFolders();
    while (folders.hasNext()) getFileIds(folders.next(), fileList, q);
    return fileList;
  };
  var sourceFiles = getFileIds(DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId), [], "mimeType='" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL + "' or mimeType='" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY + "'");
  var destinationFiles = getFileIds(DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId), [], "mimeType='" + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + "'");
  var createFiles = sourceFiles.filter(function(e) {return destinationFiles.every(function(f) {return f.fileName !== e.fileName});});
  var updateFiles = sourceFiles.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    var dst = destinationFiles.filter(function(f) {return f.fileName === e.fileName});
    if (dst.length > 0) {
      e.to = dst[0].id;
      ar.push(e);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (createFiles.length > 0) createFiles.forEach(function(e) {Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{id: destinationFolderId}], title: e.fileName}, DriveApp.getFileById(e.id))});
  if (updateFiles.length > 0) updateFiles.forEach(function(e) {Drive.Files.update({}, e.to, DriveApp.getFileById(e.id))});
}
```